Ffmpeg: Compile argument for 'delogo'
I use a custom version of ffmpeg I compiled myself (for cuda support), but when I try to use the delogo filter I get:
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x586ea2283880] No such filter: 'delogo'
[vost#0:0/mpeg4 @ 0x586ea2281cc0] Error initializing a simple filtergraph

What argument should I use when compiling in order to be able to use this filter? And can you tell me at the same time where I can find this information online? It’s not the first time I can’t use a filter because of a missing library and if I’m not mistaken, the ffmpeg documentation does not mention it. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#delogo

-enable-gpl has to be set during configure.
Dependency information can be found in the configure script. For delogo, see this line,
delogo_filter_deps="gpl"

